# Run Makefile from Finder

Tags: finder

I often travel using Finder in the source directories of various project (LaTeX articles, programming stuff) for which the compilation is piloted by a `Makefile`.
I was wondering if there is a simple way (Service menu, Automator whatever) to invoke the corresponding command (`make`) in the good directory directoly from Finder (right-click something).

I'm running OS X 10.8.

Thanks by advance for your suggestions

Comment: Not sure about 100% Finder `make`-ing, but, you could open a Terminal window and type `make` then drag the `Makefile` into the Terminal to copy the path to it.

Comment: @2rs2ts, if you go this way, type `make -C ` before dragging the `Makefile`.

Comment: @lhf Ah yes, of course.

Comment: Adding to @2rs2ts you do probably want the make in a terminal or from an editor to see the error messages

Answer (score 3):

You could use a function like this:

```
fmake() {
  cd "$(osascript -e 'tell application "Finder"
      POSIX path of (target of Finder window 1 as alias)
  end tell' 2> /dev/null)"
  make && make install
}
```

Or save a function just for the cd command and use history-search-backward to run something like `cdf && make && make install`.

Or open Automator, choose the Service template, set the input type to no input, and add a Run AppleScript action like this:

```
try
    tell application "Finder"
        POSIX path of (target of Finder window 1 as alias)
    end tell
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "cd " & quoted form of result & " && make && make install"
        activate
    end tell
end
```

Without the try block Automator would show an error dialog if the script exits with an error.

Comment: You could also pipe the stdout and std to see errors or at least prompt where the error log is

Answer (score 0):

Admitted, this is a clumsy way but maybe better than nothing:

create a text file named makeit.command and just put one line of text into it:

```
make
```

Then chomod the file 755

```
chmod 755 makeit.command
```

If you want to run a make, drag/copy it to that folder and then double click it.

Comment: In that case what is the current directory? I don't think it will be where the Makefile is and so the make will probably fail

Answer (score 0):

I like Lauri Ranta's AppleScript answer.  I was working on such a thing for myself to be able to use the Finder to locate a folder and create a git repository in a directory selected in the Finder.

I can see where you may want to call the make command on a folder as well.

It seems to me that it would be nice to be able to use the Finder's GUI and that you might want to do a lot of things with the selected directory.

[Connect to Selected Directory](http://learnbymac.com/examples/real_world_examples/automator/workflows/downloads.php#cd_service)

I think that this Automator Service is more general than issuing any kind of command for a directory inside of the AppleScript and it gets you ready to enter whatever shell command that you want to.

--- edit ---

I'm sorry, my post above didn't answer the original question. Here is a link to an Automator workflow saved as a Service that runs the make command on the directory selected in the Finder:

[Run Make](http://learnbymac.com/examples/real_world_examples/automator/workflows/downloads.php#run_make_service)

I tried this new service of mine and I didn't like it because sometimes you may want to do the shell command "make" and other times you may want to do the shell command "make && make install", or you may want to build a different target "make fullbuild" or something.  That's why I was thinking that a service called "Connect to Selected Directory" would be best.

Comment: How does this answer the question it appears to be general comments but no exact answer

Comment: I'm sorry.  I meant to provide an exact answer with a link to finished code which when downloaded would install as a Service.

Comment: There is already a preinstalled service (New Terminal at Folder) that does the same thing as your second service.

Comment: @"Lauri Ranta" Thank you.  You sure are knowledgeable.  I tried the Service "New Terminal at Folder" it didn't work for me, I think because I set a default directory in my ".bash_profile".  For some reason, my Service: "Connect to Selected Directory" works for me, but the Service: "New Terminal at Folder" does open Terminal.app, but it doesn't set the current directory correctly.  I get a current directory that is set in my ".bash_profile".

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding `#!/usr/bin/make -f` as the first line of `Makefile` and making it executable but it does not run in the correct folder. So I've settled for a solution along the lines of the answer by The-Dood.

Open a terminal and go to the folder where you have you project and `Makefile`, then type this:

```
cat <<EOF > Makeit
make -C `dirname $_`
echo 'Press enter to continue'
read
EOF
chmod +x Makeit
```

Now double-clicking `Makeit` should invoke `make` on the same folder. You can add any other arguments when calling `make` or edit `Makeit` at will.

This solution works but it may not be terribly convenient because you need a copy of `Makeit` in each folder.